# Database.update() is not updating the data, but there are no error message

Tags: dml, update, database

I am experimenting this to test Database.update() to update data partially in Developer Edition. The issue is that, it is not updating the data and is not throwing any error. I am certain that, there are no data discrepancy and it should work.

Here is my code

```
<apex:page controller="Opportunity_Mass_Edit">
<apex:form id="opportunityList">
 <apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit" title="Opportunities" >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opportunities}" var="record" >
        <apex:column value="{!record.Id}"/>
       <apex:column >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!record.Name}" 
                         />  
                        <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
      </apex:column>
    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"   /> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
     <apex:pageBlockButtons > 
               <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" reRender="opportunityList" id="saveButton" />
     </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
 </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My controller class :

```
public class Opportunity_Mass_Edit {

   List<Opportunity>  opportunities {set;get;}

    public Opportunity_Mass_Edit (){
    opportunities =     [SELECT Id, Name, CloseDate FROM Opportunity Where NOT( Name like 'Edge%')  limit 10];

}
    public PageReference save(){
      List<Opportunity> listOpp = new List<Opportunity>();
      system.debug('@@ opportunities ='+opportunities);
      Database.SaveResult[] srList =Database.update(opportunities,false);


      for(Database.SaveResult sr :srList ){
           if (sr.isSuccess()){
              system.debug('If success ' + sr.getId());
              sr.getId();
           }
           else{

              system.debug('If fail ' + sr.getId());
              // Operation failed, so get all errors                
              for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                    System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
                    System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                    System.debug('Opportunities fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
              }

           }
       }

      return null;
    }

}
```

I updated the code and it still not working until I notice this.Here the picture.How to avoid this from happen?
[image]

Comment: Either it works or not it should have some debug logs according to your code. Have you checked your debug log?

Comment: No error. I notice something , if I update the record and mouse over cursor outside the field then click Save, it will save.But if I update the record and directly click Save, it wont update. Let me update the question

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using getOpportunities as your getter, you're re-querying the records each time you perform any action. So, for example, when you click the save button, all of your edits are wiped out. If you check your records carefully, you'll notice the Last Modified Date has been updated, but the other fields have not. Consider using a normal getter/setter on the variable, and query in your constructor:

```
public class Opportunity_Mass_Edit {
    public List<Opportunity>  opportunities { get; set; }

    public Opportunity_Mass_Edit() {
       opportunities =     [SELECT Id, Name, CloseDate FROM Opportunity Where NOT( Name like 'Edge%')  limit 10];
    }
    public void save() {
        Database.update(opportunities, false);
    }
}
```

There's no need to check the error messages explicitly; when you use this technique, errors will be surfaced in the apex:pageMessages block. Make sure you add this to your page:

```
<apex:pageMessages />
```

Comment: I updated the code, still it face the same issue until I notice certain behavior on clicking Save.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working perfectly at my DE.

Only thing, I could think of it is failing because of trigger or any other processes.

By the way, according to the [SaveResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_saveresult) documentation,

> SaveResult returns ID of every record that was processed successfully, or error messages and fields of the failed records.

In case of failure `getId()` will return null in case of update also.

So `system.debug('If fail ' + sr.getId());` will return null.

Comment: No error.Please see the updated question.